# Caption Chronology Timeline LaTeX

Tags: captions, timeline, newfloat

I am writing because I am trying to add a caption to a timeline. I am using Overleaf. I am not sure how to do this properly (right now I get the error message \caption outside float)...

```
\begin{chronology}[8]{1890}{1965}{\textwidth}[\textwidth]
\event{1896}{\color{blue}{1896}}
\event[1896]{1921}{\small{Period 1}}
\event{1922}{\color{blue}{1922}}
\event[1922]{1945}{\small{Period 2}}
\event{1946}{\color{blue}{1946}}
\event[1946]{1962}{\small{Period 3}}
\event{1962}{\color{blue}{1962}}
\end{chronology}\caption{Country}
```

Instead of having "Country" to the right of the timeline I would like to have it on top as if it was the caption of a table or figure. Anyone knows how to do this? Thank you! [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your chronology with `\documentclass` at it beginning and `\end{document}` at the end, which will reproduce your problem.

Comment: If you will insert your code fragment into `figure` float it will works as is expected. Since you not provide MWE (Minimal Working Example, a complete small document)), we can only guess what you do in document.

Answer (score 2):

The caption works inside floats like tables or figures.

You can put the `chronology` within those environments, but since you probably want to customize it for this specific use, it is better to define a new environment (here called `Chronos`) and choose the settings you want: no labels or numbers, just the text with some formatting.

[image: zz]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chronology}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{caption} % custom captions
\captionsetup[Chronos]{labelformat=empty,textfont={bf,it} } % only text of the caption, in bold /italic

\usepackage{newfloat} % added <<<<<
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[placement={h!}]{Chronos} % new float <<<< 

\begin{document}

In \emph{Country} the documented  events took place during three different periods:

\begin{Chronos}
    \caption{Country}
    \begin{chronology}[8]{1890}{1965}{\textwidth}[\textwidth]
        \event{1896}{\color{blue}{1896}}
        \event[1896]{1921}{\small{Period 1}}
        \event{1922}{\color{blue}{1922}}
        \event[1922]{1945}{\small{Period 2}}
        \event{1946}{\color{blue}{1946}}
        \event[1946]{1962}{\small{Period 3}}
        \event{1962}{\color{blue}{1962}}
    \end{chronology}    
\end{Chronos}

\kant[2]

\end{document}
```